# TensorFlow with Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, pydev, tensorflow

I'm trying to run the TensorFlow Python examples for with Eclipse Mars for Mac OS X, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Unresolved import: tensorflow.python.platform
```

The error is raised on the 3rd line:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow.python.platform
```

I'm new to Python and TensorFlow. I'm using PyDev for Eclipse. I read somewhere that I can add code to the "External Libraries" folder but I'm not sure where the TensorFlow library is.

I installed TensorFlow following the [installation directions on the TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are running into a problem with your Python environment. The easiest way to deal with this is to follow these steps:

1. Install TensorFlow into a virtualenv, by following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation). This avoids the need to acquire root privileges, and makes it easier to experiment with different versions of TensorFlow. (It also avoids conflicts with other system-installed versions of different libraries.)
2. Set up PyDev to use your new virtualenv, by following step 5 onwards in [this guide](http://ntraft.com/eclipse-with-pydev-and-virtualenv/). This involves setting up a new "interpreter" whose library will be the set of libraries in the virtualenv. You may need to recreate your Eclipse project to use this interpreter.

Comment: Thanks @mrry but I'm getting a permission denied when trying to activate the virtualenv. I chmod the activate to 777 but then it just starts and immediately quits without changing the prompt.

Comment: OK I got the virtualenv to activate and changed the interpreter to point to ~/tensorflow/bin/python. Then I recreated the project. But I'm still getting the same errors. import tensorflow.python.platform is "unresolved."

Comment: this seems like a problem with my tensorflow integration on the machine and not an Eclipse problem. So your answer is good, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

1. install tensorflow.
2. in eclipse , assume you have pydev installed, go to preferences>pydev>python interpreter.
3. in the libraries tab add the path to the lib folder of your tensorflow lib folder.

here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: To add to the answer above, you might have to reimport the project and restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I also had import issues. I fixed it by creating a new project and specifying interpreter as ~/tensorflow/lib/python2.7

Eclipse seems to then point to the right interpreter and offers to import other relevant files - result is similar to answer above.

The answer from @mrry above was helpful - only the link to the 5 step guide seems to be unavailable. 
Hope this helps!

[image: Screenshot]