# How to debug A graph in tensorflow in windows

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pydev, windows-7-x64

I am trying to debug a program that use tensorflow, the problem is I can't launch the dbdp in pydev, How can to check the contain of my tensors or my layers? If any person know how to debug correctly a tensorflow program in windows, please I help me.

Thanks,

Comment: if you can't debug, just print

Comment: Can we print the flow value at the running time ?

Comment: Yes. There is an op for printing https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/Print. Also you can call `eval` of `tf.Variable`-s or generate summary for viewing in Tensorboard.

Comment: Can we pause the graph at runtimes ???

Comment: You should be able to run it in PyDev... which error do you have? Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/34887922/110451 otherwise, please try what's explained at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43004769/110451